# Find Coordinates of cropped image (JPG) from it's original

Tags: python, opencv

I have a database of original images and for each original images there are various cropped versions.

This is an example of how the image look like:

**Original**
[image: Original Image]

**Horizontal Crop**
[image: Horizontal Crop]

**Square Crop**

[image: Square Crop]

This is a very simple example, but  most images are like this, some might taken a smaller section of the original image than others.

I was looking at OpenCV in python but I'm very new to this kind of image processing.

The idea is to be able to save the cropping information separate from the image to save space and then generate all the cropping and different aspect ratio on the fly with a cache system instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method you are looking for is called "template matching". You find examples here

https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html

For your problem, given the large images, it might be a good idea to constrain the search space by resizing both images by the same factor. So that searching a position that isn't as precise, but allows then to constrain the actual full pixel sized search to a smaller region around that point.

Comment: do you have any suggestion on how to scale both images to same scale? it's not just recommendation, but won't work at all if images are of different scale. in my case the smaller image was scaled down as well, but unknown how much.

Comment: That’s tough. I think your best approach is using feature extraction and matching algorithms like SIFT and SURF to generate a mapping between two images. This then allows to gauge a scale variance and you can normalize. 

Alternatively you can try and use metrics based on scale pyramids to look for the highest degree of matching. It’s probably less robust though.